# Does crontab leave mysql connections open?

Tags: mysql, cron

When I run report jobs (get net sales data from mysql) in crontab (bashscript) , I establish a connection to mysql and get the required data.

Does this leave mysql connections open or all the connections are closed on job completion?

UPDATE - I use bash script to connect to mysql.

Comment: Could you please update your question and elaborate on how you establish the connection (Running a php script?, bash script?, provide code examples stripped of sensitive data)

Comment: Most likely not. Crontab executes a program, it doesn't however keep the program running. You can always check how many active connections there are by running `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` in your MySQL terminal.

Comment: The question *"Does crontab leave mysql connections open?"* is completely wrong.

The crontab is just a list, not code, it doesn't do anything. Even more, the cron daemon (the one that reads crontab) doesn't do anything more than launching other programs as described in the crontab.

It's the responsibility of those programs to close the connections they open. But, as soon as a program exits, be it the `mysql` client or any other program, all the connections it opens are automatically closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In basic scenarios the MySQL connections will be closed when the mysql client within the bash script finishes running.

If you are running the mysql command line Linux client within your bash script then bash would normally wait for the mysql process to exit before continuing to the end of the script.

There are ways to persist processes beyond the life of the bash script but you haven't mentioned using those in your question.

If you are using a mysql library that has a close function - most of the MySQL libraries have this in the api then you should use it. Although the default process behaviour will probably clean up open connections for you, it helps to get in the habit of closing resources that you are not going to require again within your code as this makes it more scalable and also informs other developers of your intended behaviour.

Comment: You're giving away wrong advice. If you are working on scalable apps, then you want things as efficient as possible. Closing connections is **not** efficient. This doesn't apply to crontab, but it does apply to, for example, `php-fpm` - you never want to close a connection to MySQL. If you do, then every request deals with the TCP handshake and MySQL authentication + authorization. That's inefficient. PHP programmers rarely have to worry about cleaning stuff up, and when they do clean stuff up - it just makes everything slower.

Comment: @abipc - they are. If the script exits after it's done, then the program === dead, ergo nothing to keep the connection up. As per comments, you can **verify** this behavior by executing `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` in your MySQL terminal.

Comment: Thanks @Mjh - there are different ways that application scale. Agreed that in linear scenarios, keeping a simple set of resources on tap can be a good move. My point is that it is good practice for developers to be clear in code/documentation about the desired behaviour and not assume it will always just work a specific way. I've clarified the answer slightly in this respect.

Comment: I agree with your answer, upvoted and have a nice day :)